# Warning: Creating default object from empty value header.php on line 327

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress website showing  warning in top like this Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/innappsy/public_html/ramufilms/wp-content/themes/rockit/header.php on line 327

i checked the code but not able to get because im new to the wordpress  pls tell me how to resolve this.

```
<?php 
 if(is_front_page() or is_home()){
     $show_slider = "";
     $cs_home_page_slider = get_option("cs_home_page_slider");
     if ( $cs_home_page_slider <> "" ) {
    $xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_home_page_slider);
        $show_slider = $xmlObject->show_slider;
        $node->slider_type = $xmlObject->slider_type;
        $node->slider = $xmlObject->slider_id;
     }
   ?>
```

Comment: http://themeforest.net/item/rockit-now-music-band-wordpress-theme/3278167/comments?page=38#comment_3992495

Comment: @juanrpozo: Well, there the author of the theme just says to disable error reporting to get PHP to “shut up” about the error … which most likely means they themselves have no idea of what they are doing.

Comment: I agree @CBroe - just another good place for hackers.